# Repository 'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.OAuthException: GitHub Bad credentials

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm having this error when trying to deploy an Azure Web App using Github repo.

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "<Error xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><Code>BadRequest</Code><Message>Repository 'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.OAuthException: GitHub GetSecretsPublicKey: Bad credentials&#xD;\n   at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.GitHubProxy.&lt ...
```

I used the authorize button in the Deployment Center to link the Github account. I've tried to revoke the old access from Azure in Github and tried again but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Repository 'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.OAuthException: GitHub Bad credentials

Initially even I got the same error.

[image]

This is because `Azure App Service` is not registered in `Authorized OAuth Apps`.

[image]

***Follow the below steps to regsiter the `Azure App Service`.***

- First create an `Azure App Service`.
- Navigate to `GitHub` => in Right hand pane select `Settings` => select `Developer settings` in the left hand pane => `OAuth Apps` => `Register a new Application`.

[image]

[image]

- `ClientID` and `Client Secret` will be created, copy those for later use.
- Navigate to the created `Azure App Service` => `Authentication` => `Add Identity Provider` => select `GitHub` and provide the `ClientID` and `SecretID` from `GitHub`.

[image]

- In `Azure App Service` => `Deployment center` = >select source as `GitHub` and click on `Change Account` => `Authorize AzureAppService`.

[image]

- Now you can see the `Azure App Service` in `GitHub` => `Applications` => `Authorized OAuth Apps`.

[image]

- Now Iam able to Build Application with `GitHub` in `Deployment center`.

[image]

- This settings has to be done only once.
- From next deployment, you can simply select and build GitHub source without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I got the same error. the solution was to wait for 15 minutes or so.

It is ok to get the error, just wait for some time and try to run the deployment again, it should work.